# Total derivative of vector function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

Let's asume that I have a (vector) function $f \space (s,t,u,v):\mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n.$ I would like to calculate: $\frac{d}{dt}\biggr|_{t=t_0}  f(t,t,t,t).$

Intuitively:

This should just be given by:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\biggr|_{t=t_0}  f(t,t,t,t)=\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\biggr|_{(s,t,u,v)=(t_0,t_0,t_0,t_0)}f(s,t,u,v)+\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\biggr|_{(s,t,u,v)=(t_0,t_0,t_0,t_0)}f(s,t,u,v)+\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\biggr|_{(s,t,u,v)=(t_0,t_0,t_0,t_0)}f(s,t,u,v)+\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\biggr|_{(s,t,u,v)=(t_0,t_0,t_0,t_0)}f(s,t,u,v).$$

Am I right? Can someone provide some explanation. I know this is probably a stupid question, but I'm not a mathematician and have trouble finding like a theorem or something regarding this, couldn't find something useful here on math.SE either .It seems like this just the total deriative of the function, but in this case [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative) just provides the formula for a scalar function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, in appropriate conditions, when $f$ have $n$ variables $z=f(y_1, \cdots, y_n)$ and we take its composition with functions  $y_i=\psi_i(x_1, \cdots, x_m)$, then well known chain rule is:

$$\frac{\partial f \circ \psi}{\partial x_k}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial y_1}\frac{\partial \psi_1}{\partial x_k}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y_2}\frac{\partial \psi_2}{\partial x_k}+ \cdots+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y_n}\frac{\partial \psi_n}{\partial x_k}$$

In your case $m=1, n=4$ and $\forall k=\overline{1,4}$ we have $\psi_k(t)=t$, which gives $\psi_k^{'}=1$. So your formula is right and can be written as:
$$\frac{df}{dt}= \sum_{i=1}^{4}f_{y_i}^{'}=f_{y_1}^{'}+f_{y_2}^{'}+f_{y_3}^{'}+f_{y_4}^{'}$$

Comment: Many thanks! This is what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 1):

From [this part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative#Example:_Differentiation_with_indirect_dependencies) of the same Wikipedia page, you can consider a more general version as (with a relabling of the variables)
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}\bigg\rvert_{t_0} f(t,x_1(t),x_2(t),x_3(t)) = \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial t} + \sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{d x_i}{dt} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\right) f
\end{equation}

In your case, $\frac{d x_i}{d t} = 1$ and this reduces to the formula you produced.

Comment: Thank you! I was looking at this example for $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ too, but wasn't sure if it generalises to $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$.